# How to start running a view only after you press the button on top of it?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am writing a positioning app using MapKit and CoreLocation.
and the app would track the device location and compute the distance it moves.
I now want to make a start button on top of it.
So that once I press the start button, the button disappeared and the map underneath starts showing the device's location and start calculating the distance moved.

I'm not making requests that someone will help me for the whole app. 
I just wanna know how I can start the map running ONLY after the button is pressed.

I have tried to make a empty while loop, with condition whether the button has been pressed.
that means the loop will only be terminated after you press the start button.

But this method seems stupid, and more importantly, it doesn't work in my app.

Do I need to use thread to fulfill this task?
Hope someone can give me some hints, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the button's target to a method that hides the button and then calls your CoreLocationManager's startUpdatingLocation, which will then begin returning calls to the delegate (probably your view controller) with information on the location.  While your app is waiting on the button to get pressed, you don't have to do anything; the iPhone will happily keep running its own main thread until it invokes one of your methods (such as the one you assign for when the button is pressed.)

Answer (score 1):

you can hide the "start" button

> [startButton setHidden:YES];

and when you call the button you can startUpdating your location

also you can use some animation to have the button doing a fading to transparent

good luck